# jstl formatNumber in input leads to NumberFormatException

Tags: jsp-tags

in my jsp I have this:

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" minFractionDigits="2" value="${myVal}" var="val" />
```

and I use "val" in an input field. It displays nicely (e.g. 10,000.00).
But when the form is submitted I get a NumberFormatException which didn't happen without the formatting.

I haven't found a way around this - any clues?

Thanks,
John.

Answer (score 0):

When the form is submitted this number (e.g. 10,000.00) goes back to your server(I assume). 
In that case the formatted number is now a string with a comma between 10 and 000.00
Make sure what you submit back is a valid number without any characters like comma.